# Outlook 2010 Inbox Update

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

Some users are having issues with their mailboxes not updating automatically, they need to click update folder every couple of minutes, send and receive doesn't work either for their mailboxes. The users are Personal Assistants to 3 different senior managers and have access to those mailboxes and another generic rarely used contact-us mailbox. We are using outlook 2010 with exchange cached mode. They also need to click update folder to get one of the managers calendar to update the contents. All 3 managers mailboxes and the other 2 calendars update without issue.

One of the senior managers has a 5GB mailbox, the others are 1GB or less. The issue only happens when we add the 5GB mailbox is added. The user receives emails immediately for 3 of the managers mailboxes(including the 5GB one) but not her own mailbox

The issue is obviously with the 5GB mailbox as when it's removed everything works fine.

-Why would the users own mailbox and one managers calendar not update as opposed to the 5gb or other mailboxes/calendars?

-Is there a way to prioritise which mailbox updates?

-Is there a way to re-synchronise outlook so everything works?

-Is there anything I can do to get the users working with all mailboxes/calendars etc?

-Do I need to get the 5GB mailbox reduced somehow, she's a finance person and is very concerned about losing emails?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling Exchange Cached mode for the shared mailboxes resolved this issue.